# Google Maps iOS API key not working

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a simple iOS app into which I am integrating Google Maps. However, the API key I've provided results in several of these error messages when my map view is displayed:

`ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x1818bf40 {data=<CFData 0x18137410 [0x302aec8]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = ...}}`

Here is what I have already tried to no avail:

- Calling `[GMSServices provideAPIKey:]` as the first line of code within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
- Double-checking that my API key is correct and is an iOS API key (I copy/pasted it directly from the Google Cloud Console into my app)
- Providing the API key both with `{}` and without
- Confirming my bundle name by outputting it with `[[Bundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]`
- Omitting bundle identifier restrictions altogether
- Regenerating the API key

I am not sure what else to try. My bundle name is in this format: `net.company.MyApp` and I have entered it exactly that way into the Google Cloud Console (I know bundle IDs are case-sensitive).

Could it be that Google doesn't support bundle identifiers of a certain type (e.g., with upper-case letters or beginning with `net.`)?

Comment: Related question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054346/googlemaps-gmsview-wont-display-in-ios

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the issue. Google Maps SDK for iOS must be enabled for keys to work. I already had Google Maps API v3 enabled and I thought that was enough, but it wasn't.

Comment: It would be nice if Google prompted me to enable the Google Maps SDK for iOS API as soon as I start generating keys.

Comment: I faced the same issue and have checked google maps sdk for iOS and bundle identifiers but gives me same error

Comment: for me it's not working. Please let me know what to do.

Comment: didn't help me either

Answer (score 9):

You need to enable maps service in Google developer Console. In new layout, choose **APIs & auth** section and **APIs** subitem in the left column. Next, in the right one enable **Maps SDK for iOS** by clicking on the **Off** button.

Answer (score 2):

if you are doing a manual integration of SDK, it is no longer supported in latest version. Also GoogleMapsM4B version needs to be deleted and only keep GoogleMaps SDK in your project. This worked for me.

Comment: Removing GoogleMapsM4B did it for me. Thank you